# Can someone please tell which one is right "He goes to school in Canada" or "He goes to a school in Canada"?

Tags: articles

I'm not a native speaker and I've seen this question but couldn't answer it

Which one is right "He goes to school in Canada" or "He goes to a school in Canada"

Comment: Including the article is unlikely - but it more strongly implies he *could* have gone to a school *somewhere else* (he just *happens* to have ended up attending a Canadian school, for whatever reason). Without the article, it's more likely *since* he's in Canada, that's where he goes to school. With the article, it's very likely the *reason* he's in Canada at all is so that he can go to that particular school.

Comment: For what it's worth, Google Ngrams shows 'goes to school/college/university/church' are far more common than 'goes to a school/college/university/church'. While 'a' is not wrong, I'm trying to think of a context where I would include it.

Answer (score 10):

> He goes to school in Canada.

This means that he receives formal education in Canada, at one or more institutions.

> He goes to a school in Canada.

This means that he is attending *a particular* educational institution.

Comment: "He goes to a school in Canada" could be the answer to a question such as "Does he go to a school in the USA?", or "In which country does he go to school?"

Answer (score 0):

He goes to school in Canada. We are not thinking about a particular school but about school as an institution.

Comment: Hi @Walores and welcome to ELL. When providing answers it is best to include some evidence to support your assertion. In this case, either alternative can be and is used frequently, depending on context, so you answer is not really accurate. It is also important to be confident of your own English and grammar when providing answers on a site for English learners.